# Make three selection same based on randomIndex in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below I have two arrays `items` and `notes`. `items` is an array of objects with a numeric label, and a URL image corresponding to that number.

The `notes` array has image URL's numbered from 1 to 9.

I select 3 values as **random index**, and then based off of that I select a `label`, `url` from items, and an `image` from notes.

**I'm trying to make the three selection same**, i.e.,

If the random index is 3, then..

- the label should be 3
- Url should be `https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3`
- note[randomindex] should be `https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3`

How can I achieve this? What changes do I have to make?

```js
var randomIndex;
var array2 = [];
   ptagstl = document.querySelectorAll('[name="templabel"]');
   ptagturl = document.querySelectorAll('[name="tempurl"]');
   
   
var items = [
{label:'1',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
{label:'2',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'},
{label:'3',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'},
{label:'4',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'},
{label:'5',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'},
{label:'6',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'},
{label: '7',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'},
{label:'8',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'},
{label:'9',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'}];

var notes = [
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4',                                                                                          'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'];


var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];

array2 = items.slice();
var item;

function rvalue() {

for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++)
{
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() *array2.length)

item = array2[randomIndex];
array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

tempimages.push({data: item,index: randomIndex });
notesselected.push({data: notes[randomIndex],index: randomIndex});
 
ptagstl[index].textContent = item.label;
ptagturl[index].textContent = item.url;
 
console.log(notes[randomIndex]);
 
      }
    }
rvalue();
```

```html
<p id="demo" name="templabel"></p>
<p id="demo" name="templabel"></p>
<p id="demo" name="templabel"></p>

<p id="demo" style="float:right;" name="tempurl"></p>
<p id="demo" style="float:right" name="tempurl"></p>
<p id="demo" style="float:right" name="tempurl"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "problem" is splice.

Removing the splice from your loop solves your problem. However, perhaps you don't want to be able to make the same selection, in which case, you should leave it and you are left with the current situation.

When you splice array2 and remove 1 item, **the match from index to value changes**. For example, if you have `[1,2,3]` as an array, and you remove the 2, then [1] actually returns 3. This is what you are seeing play out in your code.

Your options are to remove the splice, or alter the way the code is used. If you change its use, then perhaps just slicing a second array for notes and using that is a good idea.

Here is an example:

```js
var randomIndex;
var array2 = [];
   ptagstl = document.querySelectorAll('[name="templabel"]');
   ptagturl = document.querySelectorAll('[name="tempurl"]');
   
   
var items = [
{label:'1',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
{label:'2',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'},
{label:'3',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'},
{label:'4',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'},
{label:'5',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'},
{label:'6',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'},
{label: '7',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'},
{label:'8',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'},
{label:'9',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'}];

var notes = [
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4',                                                                                          'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'];


var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];

array2 = items.slice(); notes2 = notes.slice();
var item;

function rvalue() {

for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++)
{
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() *array2.length)

item = array2[randomIndex];

tempimages.push({data: item,index: randomIndex });
notesselected.push({data: notes2[randomIndex],index: randomIndex});
 
ptagstl[index].textContent = item.label;
ptagturl[index].textContent = item.url;
 
console.log(notes2[randomIndex]);
array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
notes2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
 
      }
    }
rvalue();
```

```html
<p id="demo" name="templabel"></p>
<p id="demo" name="templabel"></p>
<p id="demo" name="templabel"></p>

<p id="demo" style="float:right;" name="tempurl"></p>
<p id="demo" style="float:right" name="tempurl"></p>
<p id="demo" style="float:right" name="tempurl"></p>
```

Comment: how to avoid duplicates in this selection if i remove splice?

Comment: @batman -  Using splice was a good approach for preventing duplicates. If you see in my example in this answer, splice is still used, it is just also extended to the notes array as well so that you can both avoid duplicates while still retaining the match you were looking for.

Comment: @TravisJ I did not understand the use of `splice` as you said in your comment that splice is used to prevent duplicates but when I do it for an array with duplicate values it doesn't affect the array. Can you please explain? Thanks :)

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil - Well, these values are unique, so there are no duplicates there, and splice wont help with that. What splice does help with is *selection*. As splice removes an item, it is impossible to then select it a second time, therefore preventing duplicate *selection*.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly this is what you will need you are using slice while it's not even needed.

Try the code below (it works):

```
    var randomIndex;


        // var array2 = [];

        ptagstl = document.querySelectorAll('[name="templabel"]');
        ptagturl = document.querySelectorAll('[name="tempurl"]');


        var items = [{
                    label: '1',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'
              },
              {
                    label: '2',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'
              },
              {
                    label: '3',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'
              },
              {
                    label: '4',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'
              },
              {
                    label: '5',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'
              },
              {
                    label: '6',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'
              },
              {
                    label: '7',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'
              },
              {
                    label: '8',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'
              },
              {
                    label: '9',
                    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'
              }
        ];

        var notes = [
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4', 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
        ];


        var tempimages = [];
        var notesselected = [];

        //this pupulates the above stacks with random values depending upon the number passed to it
        function getImageStacks(n) {

              debugger;

              for (var index = 0; index < n; index++) {


                    debugger;

                    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (items.length) + 1);

                    //creating two empty objects
                    var ImageObject = {};
                    var NoteObject = {};

                    //adding values for the Image/Items
                    ImageObject.label = items[randomIndex -1].label;
                    ImageObject.url = items[randomIndex -1].url;

                    //adding values for the Notes
                    NoteObject.note = notes[randomIndex -1];

                    // item = array2[randomIndex];
                    // array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

                    //Pushing the values
                    tempimages.push({
                          data: ImageObject,
                          index: randomIndex
                    });
                    notesselected.push({
                          data: NoteObject,
                          index: randomIndex
                    });

              }

              //printing the values
              console.log(tempimages);
              console.log(notesselected);
        }

        //calling function

        //function caller
        getImageStacks(3);
```

Comment: thaks for explanation.